# Using both Compass and Autoprefixer in Grunt

Tags: javascript, css, gruntjs

Curious about whether there’s a way to use both Autoprefixer and Compass in Grunt without having to specify a different output path for each task.

I currently have my .scss files in a folder named `source`. The compass task compiles these into a folder named `build`. I want to then run Autoprefixer without having to specify another different output path (i.e. still be in the `build` directory).

Is it not possible to run Autoprefixer on a compass compiled CSS file without specifying a different output path? Is it possible to run both at the same time perhaps?

Here’s the section of my gruntfile it relates to if it’s of any help. What I run in terminal is `grunt watch`:

```
compass: {
    options: {
        sassDir: 'style/source',
        cssDir: 'style/build',
        outputStyle: 'expanded',
    }
},
watch: {
    css: {
        files: ['style/source/**/*.scss'],
        tasks: ['compass'],
        options: {
            spawn: false,
        }
    }
},
```

Refs:

https://github.com/nDmitry/grunt-autoprefixer

https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass

Answer (score 1):

If you do not specify an output location for Autoprefixer, it will just use the input location and overwrite the files. Here’s the updated section of the gruntfile if it’s of help to anyone:

```
autoprefixer: {
    css: {
        src: 'style/build/**.css',
    }
},
watch: {
    options: {
        livereload: true,
    },
    css: {
        files: ['style/source/**/*.scss'],
        tasks: ['compass', 'autoprefixer:css'],
        options: {
            spawn: false,
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to add [map: true](https://github.com/nDmitry/grunt-autoprefixer#optionsmap) to the autoprefixer call.
Here is a working copy for your goal :

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    autoprefixer: {
      css: {
          src: 'css/*.css',
          options: {
            map: true
          }
      }
    },
    compass: {
      css: {
        options: {
          config: 'config.rb'
        }
      }
    },
    watch: {
      css: {
        files: '**/*.scss',
        tasks: ['compass:css', 'autoprefixer:css'],
        options: {
            interrupt: true
        }
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-autoprefixer');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compass');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);
  
};
```